# How can I remove data from an array using regexp?

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have this array, `$array` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_139.jpg
    [1] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_134.jpg
    [2] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_138.jpg
    [3] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_138.jpg
    [4] => http://download.server.com/18821_ABS_132.jpg
    [5] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_138.jpg
)
```

and in this case, I am looking for any line that has `ABS` inside.

I could look for that by using the regexp `http://.+ABS.+`, and this will select the entire line.

But I still need to remove it from the array, not just replace it (or leave it empty.)  But in this case, the array will become:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_139.jpg
    [1] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_134.jpg
    [2] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_138.jpg
    [3] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_138.jpg
    [4] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_138.jpg
)
```

Any ideas what method i need to use?

Thanks.

edit:

i am using OOP php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a custom callback.

Example:

```
function testABS($elem) {
    return strpos($elem, 'ABS') === false;
}

print_r(array_filter($the_array, 'testABS'));
```

**Note:** This is a contrived example. You will need to adjust the logic in the *callback function* to meet your needs.

Comment: Strpos would be better than using preg_match in this case as it's faster.

Comment: The *element* at index. Read up on `array_filter()`.

Comment: i've tried this case, but doesnt work:

`public function hasABC($elem) {return strpos('ABC', $elem) !== false;}` and then `$the_array = array_filter($the_array, $this->hasABC($the_array));`

Comment: also form a OOP perspective `'testABS'` is not going through as a good callback

Comment: You didn't mentioned anything about OOP, `array_filter()` takes a *callback*. Also see the code update.

Comment: @Patrioticcow If you are using PHP 5.3+ you can use an inline function: `$array = array_filter($array, function($x){ return strpos($x, 'ABC') === false; });`

Comment: hmmm, it doesn't error out, but it doesn't change the result set as well. I get the original array

Comment: Note @PaulP.R.O. did **ABC** not **ABS**.

Comment: @Patrioticcow What Jason said, my bad. Thanks for correcting that Jason.

Answer (score 1):

There's [preg_grep](http://ca.php.net/preg_grep):

```
$abs = preg_grep('/ABS/', $your_array);
```

and returns the matches as an array. It also has a flag to return only the non-matching entries, which is probably what you want: return all entries which do NOT have 'abs' in them.

Comment: this returns that exact line that contains `ABS`, i need the array without that line

Comment: @Patrioticcow you should **read** the answer and the manual before complaining

Answer (score 1):

What i understood is u want to remove that element from the array.
can do like this.

```
$arr = Array
(
    [0] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_139.jpg
    [1] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_134.jpg
    [2] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_138.jpg
    [3] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_138.jpg
    [4] => http://download.server.com/18821_ABS_132.jpg
    [5] => http://download.server.com/18821_SM_138.jpg
);

$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $link){
  if(!preg_match('ABS', $link)){
    $new_arr[] = $link;
  }
}

//ths will give array with only 4 elements as '18821_ABS_132.jpg' will be removed

return $new_arr;
```